# Foreign Keys in MySQL Workbench not working?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am reverse engineering a database in MySQL Workbench but it doesn't seem to be importing or recognising the foreign keys. Which means I cant get it to draw the relationships.

While I am trying to get this to work I am using a snippet of a couple of tables, so its nothing complex.

Here are the 2 demo tables that I am trying to get to work:

```
    CREATE TABLE users (
    UserID varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    OrgID varchar(6) NOT NULL,  
    RegionID int NULL,
    LocationID int NULL,
    Name nvarchar(60) NULL,
    Crypt varchar(32) NULL,
    Security int NULL,
    Status int NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( UserID ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_OrgID_Users FOREIGN KEY (OrgID) REFERENCES Organisations(OrgID)
);


CREATE TABLE Organisations(
    OrgID varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(70) NOT NULL,
    Address1 varchar(50) NULL,
    Address2 varchar(50) NULL,
    Address3 varchar(50) NULL,
    Town varchar(20) NULL,
    County varchar(20) NULL,
    PostCode varchar(10) NULL,
    NotificationEmail varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( OrgID )   
)
```

But in MySQL Workbench, there are no relationships or foreign keys being created. If I look at the table data, and the foreign keys tab, theres nothing there?

I think I'm creating the foreign keys correctly, so is there a reason its not importing them?

Comment: These 2 tables already created or you are going to create them.

Answer (score 6):

On further research there were several things that I needed to do for this to work.

I had to make sure that the tables reverse engineered from MySQL were defined as InnoDB.

And I also had to remove the foreign key constraint from the create table command and create the foreign keys after the tables were created, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    OrgID varchar(6) NOT NULL,  
    RegionID int NULL,
    LocationID int NULL,
    Name nvarchar(60) NULL,
    Crypt varchar(32) NULL,
    Security int NULL,
    Status int NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( UserID )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Organisations(
    OrgID varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(70) NOT NULL,
    Address1 varchar(50) NULL,
    Address2 varchar(50) NULL,
    Address3 varchar(50) NULL,
    Town varchar(20) NULL,
    County varchar(20) NULL,
    PostCode varchar(10) NULL,
    NotificationEmail varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( OrgID )   
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_OrgID_Users FOREIGN KEY (OrgID) REFERENCES Organisations(OrgID);
```

This then worked fine and the relationships were visible and connected in MySQL Workbench